# What is the yolo v8 default grid size?

Tags: yolo

YOLO uses a grid where the centers of the detected objects are allocated. In the initial paper the grid was 7x7

**What is the grid size in Yolo v8?**

The reason I am asking is because of the anchor-free detection, as it no longer calculates depending on the offset from the anchor boxes, but uses the center.

Answer (score 1):

80x80, 40x40 and 20x20 is the size of grid_cell assuming an input image of [3, 640, 640].

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/27466624/239739723-57391d0f-1848-4388-9f30-88c2fb79233f.jpg

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34870737)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).